# Do shops have to provide printed receipt for transaction in California? Do we have to go into the mart for receipt at gas station?

Tags: california, business, receipts

Sure, if we can go into the food mart at the gas station for printed receipt. At the same time, I drop off some package  at UPS at Walgreens locations, Walgreens employees can't private any print receipt, but only provide the option for me to enter my personal email address. (sure, packages are paid online, and we can print/download the receipt).

1. Can we as payers requires some sort of print receipt when drop off packages ?
2. Do shops have to provide printed receipt for transaction in California? Can shop just provide the options of digital ones?

Answer (score 1):

### Sometimes

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### [Tax invoices](https://www.ato.gov.au/businesses-and-organisations/gst-excise-and-indirect-taxes/gst/tax-invoices)

For a business registered for Goods and Services Tax (GST) “[i]f a customer asks for a tax invoice, you must provide one within 28 days, unless it is for a sale of $82.50 (including GST) or less.”

There is no particular method specificity for the provision and there is no obligation to indicate whether the invoice has been paid (and would therefore function as a receipt).

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

### [Receipts](https://www.fairtrading.nsw.gov.au/trades-and-businesses/business-essentials/selling-goods-and-services/receipts#:%7E:text=A%20business%20has%20an%20obligation,the%20consumer%20asks%20for%20one.)

> A business has an obligation to provide proof of transaction to consumers for goods or services valued at $75 (excluding GST) or more. Businesses are also required to provide a receipt for any transaction under $75 within  seven days, if the consumer asks for one.

> If a consumer asks for an itemised bill, you must give the consumer the itemised bill, without charge, within seven days of the request. It must be expressed in plain language, legible and clear.